# Will a C program for Windows 98 run in Windows 7?

Tags: c, windows-7, backwards-compatibility, windows-98

I am performing this project but there is problem of program .

we chose a program based on the 'C' language that runs on window 98.

But we need to run this program in window 7. So same program will run or not?
if not then what to do.

Comment: This is a very broad question I guess.

Comment: Low level hardware interaction(eg bios) will not work for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Just try it:
.. at worst it won't work and shouldn't harm anything
.. at best it will function as it does in 98 and you're golden.

Whether or not it will have any real problems working as intended depends upon too many unprovided details.

One thing I can say:  if it's a 16-bit application and your Windows7 installation is 64-bit (vice 32-bit), you're far less likely to succeed in getting it running.  In that situation I recommend finding a modern program that supports the functionality you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will or maybe it won't. Windows 7 can run 16 bit applications in XP mode , but unless you can provide more information about the application or the source code there is no way to tell without simply testing.